# jfreechart panelChart can't find symbol

Tags: java, jfreechart

So I've imported the following to the needed library already. But panelChart can't find symbol. Tried creating a new file on desktop and then copying from the file on desktop but it still did not work. Tried absolute path and it also did not change anything.

```
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
jcommon-1.0.23.jar
jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar
jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar
jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
jfreesvg-2.0.jar
junit-4.11.jar
orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar
orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar
servlet.jar
swtgraphics2d.jar
```

Also, already directly imported the following into the class.

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

panelChart.removeALL();
panelChart.add(barPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER );
panelChart.validate();
```

panelChart is underlined in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following a [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jz8-ap--ZUA), and I did not realize he had renamed his `JPanel` from the default name to `panelChart`. In case you are following a similar video and run into the same problem, just change the variable name to `panelChart` from, usually, `jPanel1`, `jPanel2` etc.